# OpenGL: What may be the cause of the error "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED"?

Tags: macos, opengl, xcode6, relative-path

Finally I found that it's **the issue of relative file path**.
The fragment code file and the vertex code file are not found with my relative file path. So no code was sent to the shader.
I changed relative file path with absolute path, the project worked well.

--------------------------------Following are more details about my project---------------------------------------

- Xcode version: 6.1 (6A1052c)
- iOS version: OS X E Capitan 10.11.6 (15G31)
- GFX card: Intel Iris 1536 MB
- Code of vertex shader:

  ```
  #version 330 core
  layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
  layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
  layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

  out vec3 ourColor;
  out vec2 TexCoord;

  void main()
  {
      gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
      ourColor = color;
      TexCoord = vec2( texCoord.x , 1.0 - texCoord.y );
  }
  ```
- Code of fragment shader:

  ```
  #version 330 core
  in vec3 ourColor;
  in vec2 TexCoord;

  out vec4 color;

  uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;

  void main()
  {
      color = texture(ourTexture1,TexCoord ) * vec4(ourColor,1.0);
  }
  ```

----------------------------------Following is my original question-----------------------------------------------

I met a problem with OpenGL programming, the console output is like this:

[image]

The log is empty.

I've checked my code for several times and I really didn't know what the cause could be.

So can anyone tell me what may the cause be ?

Following is my shader code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>

class Shader
{
public:
GLuint Program;

// Constructor generates the shader on the fly
Shader( const GLchar *vertexPath, const GLchar *fragmentPath )
{
    // 1. Retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
    std::string vertexCode;
    std::string fragmentCode;
    std::ifstream vShaderFile;
    std::ifstream fShaderFile;
    // ensures ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
    vShaderFile.exceptions ( std::ifstream::badbit );
    fShaderFile.exceptions ( std::ifstream::badbit );
    try
    {
        // Open files
        vShaderFile.open( vertexPath );
        fShaderFile.open( fragmentPath );
        std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
        // Read file's buffer contents into streams
        vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf( );
        fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf( );
        // close file handlers
        vShaderFile.close( );
        fShaderFile.close( );
        // Convert stream into string
        vertexCode = vShaderStream.str( );
        fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str( );
    }
    catch ( std::ifstream::failure e )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
    }
    const GLchar *vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str( );
    const GLchar *fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str( );
    // 2. Compile shaders
    GLuint vertex, fragment;
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    // Vertex Shader
    vertex = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL );
    glCompileShader( vertex );
    // Print compile errors if any
    glGetShaderiv( vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );
    std::cout <<"Vertex::" << success << std::endl;
    if ( !success )
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog( vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    // Fragment Shader
    fragment = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL );
    glCompileShader( fragment );
    // Print compile errors if any
    glGetShaderiv( fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );
    std::cout <<"Fragment::" << success << std::endl;
    if ( !success )
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog( fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    // Shader Program
    this->Program = glCreateProgram( );
    glAttachShader( this->Program, vertex );
    glAttachShader( this->Program, fragment );
    glLinkProgram( this->Program );
    // Print linking errors if any
    glGetProgramiv( this->Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success );
    std::cout <<"linking::" << success << std::endl;

    if (!success)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog( this->Program, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
    glDeleteShader( vertex );
    glDeleteShader( fragment );

}
// Uses the current shader
void Use( )
{
    glUseProgram( this->Program );
}

};
```

Comment: Could you attach the code of fragment shader and vertex shader? That might be the useful clue for your question.

Comment: and also add what gfx card,driver and OS you got as it can be a driver bug related...

Comment: also, you can check the `glGetShaderInfoLog` not only for compilation failure but also for possible warnings that might illuminate the reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've found that it's the issue of relative path. The fragment shader code and vertex shader code are not read into shaders. I changed it with absolute path, it worked. But I tried many forms of relative path, it all failed.

Comment: if you have a different question you should open a new question instead of editing your existing question. Also for "What is the right form of relative file path in Xcode?" you need to ask yourself "relative to what" and then either change the "current directory" via OS specific APIs or prepend the absolute path you want it to be realtive to yourself.

Comment: Yes, thanks for ur advice~

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found that it's the issue of **relative file path**. The fragment code file and the vertex code file are not found with my relative file path. So no code was sent to the shader. I changed relative file path with absolute path, the project worked well.

Comment: In Xcode I have this problem too. I don't want to use absolute paths. How can I use relative? They don't work.